# linux-sunxi - make failed, undefined references clk_*

Tags: linux, debian, make, arm

I try to build uImage for [linux-sunxi](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/linux-sunxi) on a Debian box, which is prepared like this ([How To Build Debian From Source Code for Mele](http://rhombus-tech.net/allwinner_a10/hacking_the_mele_a1000/Building_Debian_From_Source_Code_for_Mele/)):

```
apt-get install emdebian-archive-keyring
apt-get install gcc-4.4-arm-linux-gnueabi
apt-get build-essential git
apt-get uboot-mkimage
apt-get libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

I am following the guide at [FirstSteps](http://linux-sunxi.org/FirstSteps) and have done all instructions without errors.

`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- defconfig` works, but `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- -j5 uImage` fails:

```
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux1
arch/arm/common/built-in.o: In function `sp804_get_clock_rate':
timer-sp.c:(.init.text+0x31c): undefined reference to `clk_get_sys'
timer-sp.c:(.init.text+0x364): undefined reference to `clk_put'
timer-sp.c:(.init.text+0x398): undefined reference to `clk_put'
arch/arm/mach-versatile/built-in.o: In function `versatile_init_early':
versatile_ab.c:(.init.text+0x134): undefined reference to `clkdev_add_table'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `clcdfb_remove':
hid-input.c:(.text+0xd790): undefined reference to `clk_put'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `clcdfb_probe':
hid-input.c:(.text+0xdc70): undefined reference to `clk_get'
hid-input.c:(.text+0xde04): undefined reference to `clk_put'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `amba_get_enable_pclk':
hid-input.c:(.text+0xe448): undefined reference to `clk_get'
hid-input.c:(.text+0xe470): undefined reference to `clk_put'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `amba_put_disable_pclk':
hid-input.c:(.text+0xe49c): undefined reference to `clk_put'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `pl011_remove':
hid-input.c:(.text+0x2b6c4): undefined reference to `clk_put'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `pl011_probe':
hid-input.c:(.text+0x2c234): undefined reference to `clk_get'
hid-input.c:(.text+0x2c318): undefined reference to `clk_put'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `enable_clock':
hid-input.c:(.text+0x3a004): undefined reference to `clk_get'
hid-input.c:(.text+0x3a01c): undefined reference to `clk_put'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `disable_clock':
hid-input.c:(.text+0x3a044): undefined reference to `clk_get'
hid-input.c:(.text+0x3a05c): undefined reference to `clk_put'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `__pm_clk_remove':
hid-input.c:(.text+0x3a1b8): undefined reference to `clk_put'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `pm_clk_add':
hid-input.c:(.text+0x3a424): undefined reference to `clk_get'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `mmc_io_rw_extended':
hid-input.c:(.text+0x6d9ac): undefined reference to `sunximmc_check_r1_ready'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `amba_kmi_probe':
hid-input.c:(.devinit.text+0x8bc): undefined reference to `clk_get'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `amba_kmi_remove':
hid-input.c:(.devexit.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `clk_put'
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Fel 1
```

Here is a complete dump: http://pastie.org/5351582

I have tried google the errors codes, but I cannot find anything about the several references to `clk_*`, what are these functions and how do I install them on Debian?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I got this errors by running wrong make targets: `make defconfig` should be `make sun4i_defconfig`.